# Removing associated controls

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview, controls, tabcontrol

There is a `TreeView` control on the `WinForm` which is represents set of hierarchically structured objects. Each object has set of objects of some class. There is `DataGridView`, which represents that objects associated with selected `TreeView` node. By doubleclicking on the `DataRow` in the `DataGridView` on the `TabControl1` adds new `TabPage` with `DataGridView` which represents detailed values (collection of objects of some class) of the object associated with the selected `DataRow`. By doubleclicking on the `DataRow` in `TabControl1` in the `TabControl2` adds new `TabPage` with `DataGridView` which represents detailed values (collection of objects of some class) of the object associated with the doubleclicked `DataRow`. Then we can navigate by `TreeView` and see detailed info and create new TabPages by doubleclicking on DataRows. Now, when i remove the `TreeNode` from `TreeView`, i need to remove all TabPages (with DataGridViews) associated with that `TreeNode`.

Is there design pattern for centralized creation and deletion chain of associated controls?

[image: form model]

Answer (score 1):

If DataGridView1, TabControl1, and TablControl2 are always going to be present in the form (as opposed to separate UserControls set in Panels), then add a method into the TreeView's BeforeSelect Event. In the event, call methods to clear each of the other control's data out. If you do go the UserControls route, it might be better to make an Interface with a ClearData method to step down through each control.

In each of those methods, check to see if the DataGridView or Tabs are there (since the user might not have gotten down to TabControl2 yet, etc), and remove them from the parent controls.

It's not a pattern, but it should do the trick. If you need more details, or I'm missing something, it would help to not be as abstract.

I don't think there would be a pattern to load everything centrally, since each step depends on user input.

Comment: In the event, call methods to clear each of the other control's data out. I don't need to clear out the controls. I need remove all associated controls when i remove the node.

Comment: Then as you create each of the controls, set the Tag of those controls to the object represented in the TreeView. When you remove the nodes, use those methods (by passing in the object from the Treeview) and process through each of the controls in each section, and remove the controls where the tag equals that object.

Comment: Oh, yes, but it is very trivial solution. Maybe there is a decision which, as ControlManager or something like that, who can solve this problem comprehensively.